# binary tree and arrays problem. Anyone can help me to find solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, binary, html-lists

[image: Visual representation how binary tree look]

```
const cities = [

    {
      _id: "A01",
      name: "London",
      ancestors: [],
      children: ["A02", "A27"],
      parent: null
    },
    {
      _id: "A02",
      name: "Venezia",
      ancestors: ["A01"],
      children: ["A03", "A15"],
      parent: "A01"
    },
    {
      _id: "A03",
      name: "Barcelona",
      ancestors: ["A01", "A02"],
      children: ["A04", "A07"],
      parent: "A02"
    },
    {
      _id: "A04",
      name: "Atina",
      ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A03"],
      children: [],
      parent: "A03"
    },
    {
      _id: "A07",
      name: "Lisabon",
      ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A03"],
      children: [],
      parent: "A03"
    },
    {
      _id: "A15",
      name: "New York",
      ancestors: ["A01", "A02"],
      children: ["A16", "A17"],
      parent: "A02"
    },
    {
      _id: "A16",
      name: "Pariz",
      ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A15"],
      children: [],
      parent: "A15"
    },
    {
      _id: "A17",
      name: "Madrid",
      ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A15"],
      children: [],
      parent: "A15"
    },
    { _id: "A27", 
    name: "Rim", 
    ancestors: ["A01"], 
    children: [], 
    parent: "A01" 
    }
  ];
  
  const stud = "A03";
  //make array which contains elemnet with this id and his ancestors then show names as elements (list-items) in HTML

  const nbg = "A02";
  // make array which contains element with this id and descendants (direct and indirect) then show names as elements (list-items) in HTML
```

In HTML page I have 2 div

```html
<div id="nbg"></div>
<div id="stud"></div>
```

This is solution
list – item output resault:

```
London
Rim
Venezia
New York
Barcelona
Atina
Pariz
Lisabon
Mardid
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `cities` already seems to be in the shape that is being asked for in the question. Is it only a matter of creating 2 different lists for UI? Somehow I am confused when I am reading the `solution list -- item output result` given in the question.

Comment: 2 different ul gives one. That is how i figure out. I try some task from binary tree but I never have something like this. This is task for job from an interview...

Comment: You present *one* expected output, but there are two assignments and two output elements. Can you provide the expected output for both, separately? Is there any *order* of cities that the output must follow? For instance, I am surprised to see the order "Atina", "Pariz", "Lisabon", "Madrid" at the end of the expected output. They seem to follow a kind of zig-zag order when looking in the tree.

Comment: Why is "Rim" in the expected output? I don't see how that city should be in the answer to either assignment. It is not an ancestor of A03, nor is it a descendant of A02. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two recursive functions for each task (finding ancestors and finding descendants).

Try like below.

```js
const cities = [ { _id: "A01", name: "London", ancestors: [], children: ["A02", "A27"], parent: null, }, { _id: "A02", name: "Venezia", ancestors: ["A01"], children: ["A03", "A15"], parent: "A01", }, { _id: "A03", name: "Barcelona", ancestors: ["A01", "A02"], children: ["A04", "A07"], parent: "A02", }, { _id: "A04", name: "Atina", ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A03"], children: [], parent: "A03", }, { _id: "A07", name: "Lisabon", ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A03"], children: [], parent: "A03", }, { _id: "A15", name: "New York", ancestors: ["A01", "A02"], children: ["A16", "A17"], parent: "A02", }, { _id: "A16", name: "Pariz", ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A15"], children: [], parent: "A15", }, { _id: "A17", name: "Madrid", ancestors: ["A01", "A02", "A15"], children: [], parent: "A15", }, { _id: "A27", name: "Rim", ancestors: ["A01"], children: [], parent: "A01" }, ];

const stud = "A03";
//make array which contains elemnet with this id and his ancestors then show names as elements (list-items) in HTML

const nbg = "A02";
// make array which contains element with this id and descendants (direct and indirect) then show names as elements (list-items) in HTML

const findCity = (cities, id) => {
  return cities.find((city) => city._id === id);
};

// find ancestor city names starting from node with id
const findAncestors = (cities, id) => {
  let cityNames = new Set();
  const city = findCity(cities, id);
  city.ancestors.forEach((cityId) => {
    const ancestorCity = findCity(cities, cityId);
    cityNames.add(ancestorCity.name);
    cityNames = new Set([
      ...cityNames,
      ...findAncestors(cities, ancestorCity._id),
    ]);
  });

  return cityNames;
};

// find descendant city names starting from node with id
const findDescendants = (cities, id) => {
  let cityNames = new Set();
  const city = findCity(cities, id);
  city.children.forEach((cityId) => {
    const descendantCity = findCity(cities, cityId);
    cityNames.add(descendantCity.name);
    cityNames = new Set([
      ...cityNames,
      ...findDescendants(cities, descendantCity._id),
    ]);
  });

  return cityNames;
};

console.log("ancestors");
console.log(Array.from(findAncestors(cities, stud)));
console.log("descendants");
console.log(Array.from(findDescendants(cities, nbg)));
```

Comment: Thank you for solution! But something is wrong. :/ Something is confusing with this list-items result. What ever i try i don't get it right..
When i try your solution Rim is gone.. And rest is ok but not sorted as it mentioned in result output..  Hmm.. I don't get id.. :D

Comment: @Stefan Djordjevic, can you explain the question a bit more with the output?

Comment: Amelia, that is all i get. This is my task from interview for job. I have only jpg about visual binary tree presentation. First parent is London left is Rim right is Venezia. Rim doesn't have children. Venezia has2 children left is New York right is Barcelona. New York has left Paris right Madrid. And Barcelona have 2 children left Atina right Lisabon. That's it..

Comment: @Stefan Djordjevic, can you attach the image to the question as to be sure to no info is missed here

Comment: Amelia i just attached jpg. And i don't know how to format again like you do before. First time i add some post i don't know yet how to format or write well. sry. :(

Comment: great!! cities array something you created right?

Comment: I guess that this 2 array (nbg and stud) should give one solution. They should give result as i write top. I will ask company for solution and will put here if they give me. 
This task is not so hard to do but in some way is hard for me. I just don't understand him right..